# convert list of strings to numpy array of pre-set dtype

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a list of strings *string_list* that I want to convert to a 1-element structured numpy array of pre-specified dtype:

```
string_list = ['123', '45', '6.7']
my_dtype = np.dtype([('a','i4'),('b','f4'),('c','f8')])
```

The output result I want is:

```
array([(123, 45., 6.7)], dtype=[('a', '<i4'), ('b', '<f4'), ('c', '<f8')])
```

Is there a *np.astype* syntax trick for this conversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input for 'rows' of structure arrays is tuples:

```
In [464]: np.array([tuple(string_list)],dtype=my_dtype)
Out[464]: 
array([(123, 45.0, 6.7)], 
      dtype=[('a', '<i4'), ('b', '<f4'), ('c', '<f8')])
```

Another useful trick is to create an empty array of the required `dtype`, and fill in fields, one at a time.  Or fill row by row with tuples, or multiple rows with a list of tuples.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT see @hpaulj answer**. List has to be converted to tuple and list generates error.

with me this works, is that what you want?

```
string_list = ('123', '45.', '6.7')
b = np.array([string_list], dtype=[('a', '<i4'), ('b', '<f4'), ('c', '<f8')])
```

numpy version 1.8.2

Comment: Yes, the tuple conversion is all I was missing. Thanks!